# How to create sparse tensor in tensorflow with JAVA

Tags: java, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, tensor

In TensorFlow java api, I can use

```
int matrix[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };
Tensor t = Tensor.create(matrix)
```

to build a dense tensor, but how can I build a sparse tensor in java, with python, it can be coded as

```
tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1, 2], dense_shape=[3, 4])
```

When I build a Model in python, and use `tf.placeholder_with_default(input, shape, name=None)` to input, how can I use these model in Java without sparse tensor online?